# Sum amount last 6 month prior to the date of transaction

Tags: r, performance, data.table, aggregation, purrr

This is my transaction data. It shows the transactions made from the accounts in `from` column to the accounts in `to` column with the date and the amount information

```
data 

id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <fctr>  <fctr>      <date>      <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  700.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  600.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  1000.0
…           …       …           …           …
1056317     7819    7454        2010-12-31  60.2
1056318     6164    7497        2010-12-31  107.5
1056319     7533    7492        2010-12-31  164.1
```

I want to calculate how much transaction amount the accounts in `from` column received in the last 6 month prior to the date that particular transaction was made and want to save this information as a new column.

This following code works very well to accomplish this in a small dataset ,say, with 1000 rows:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  mutate(total_trx_amount_received_in_last_sixmonth= map2_dbl(from, date, 
~sum(amount[to == .x & between(date, .y - 180, .y)])))
```

However, since my data has over 1 million rows, this code will take more than a couple of hours to complete.
I searched the internet if I can speed up the run time of this code. I tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005938/how-to-make-purrr-map-function-run-faster) on SO about how to make `purrr` `map` function run faster. So, I tried the following code and instead of `mutate` of `dplyr` I used `data.table` to speed up the code even faster:

```
library(future)
library(data.table)
library(furrr)
data[, total_trx_amount_received_in_last_sixmonth:= furrr::future_pmap_dbl(list(from, date), 
~mean(amount[to == .x & between(date, .y-180, .y)])) ]
```

But, the speed hasn't been improved at all.

Is there any suggestion on how can I make the code run faster?

dput() output of the data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  id = c(
    18529L, 13742L, 9913L, 956L, 2557L, 1602L, 18669L, 35900L,
    48667L, 51341L, 53713L, 60126L, 60545L, 65113L, 66783L, 83324L,
    87614L, 88898L, 89874L, 94765L, 100277L, 101587L, 103444L, 108414L,
    113319L, 121516L, 126607L, 130170L, 131771L, 135002L, 149431L,
    157403L, 157645L, 158831L, 162597L, 162680L, 163901L, 165044L,
    167082L, 168562L, 168940L, 172578L, 173031L, 173267L, 177507L,
    179167L, 182612L, 183499L, 188171L, 189625L, 193940L, 198764L,
    199342L, 200134L, 203328L, 203763L, 204733L, 205651L, 209672L,
    210242L, 210979L, 214532L, 214741L, 215738L, 216709L, 220828L,
    222140L, 222905L, 226133L, 226527L, 227160L, 228193L, 231782L,
    232454L, 233774L, 237836L, 237837L, 238860L, 240223L, 245032L,
    246673L, 247561L, 251611L, 251696L, 252663L, 254410L, 255126L,
    255230L, 258484L, 258485L, 259309L, 259910L, 260542L, 262091L,
    264462L, 264887L, 264888L, 266125L, 268574L, 272959L
  ),
  from = c(
    "5370", "5370", "5370", "8605", "5370", "6390", "5370", "5370", "8934",
    "5370", "5635", "6046", "5680", "8026", "9037", "5370", "7816", "8046",
    "5492", "8756", "5370", "9254", "5370", "5370", "7078", "6615", "5370",
    "9817", "8228", "8822", "5735", "7058", "5370", "8667", "9315", "6053",
    "7990", "8247", "8165", "5656", "9261", "5929", "8251", "5370", "6725",
    "5370", "6004", "7022", "7442", "5370", "8679", "6491", "7078", "5370",
    "5370", "5370", "5658", "5370", "9296", "8386", "5370", "5370", "5370",
    "9535", "5370", "7541", "5370", "9621", "5370", "7158", "8240", "5370",
    "5370", "8025", "5370", "5370", "5370", "6989", "5370", "7059", "5370",
    "5370", "5370", "9121", "5608", "5370", "5370", "7551", "5370", "5370",
    "5370", "5370", "9163", "9362", "6072", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370",
    "5370"
  ),
  to = c(
    "9356", "5605", "8567", "5370", "5636", "5370", "8933", "8483", "5370",
    "7626", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "9676", "5370", "5370",
    "5370", "5370", "9105", "5370", "9772", "6979", "5370", "5370", "7564",
    "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8744", "5370", "5370", "5370",
    "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", "7318", "5370",
    "8433", "5370", "5370", "5370", "7122", "5370", "5370", "5370", "8566",
    "6728", "9689", "5370", "8342", "5370", "5370", "5614", "5596", "5953",
    "5370", "7336", "5370", "7247", "5370", "7291", "5370", "5370", "6282",
    "7236", "5370", "8866", "8613", "9247", "5370", "6767", "5370", "9273",
    "7320", "9533", "5370", "5370", "8930", "9343", "5370", "9499", "7693",
    "7830", "5392", "5370", "5370", "5370", "7497", "8516", "9023", "7310",
    "8939"
  ),
  date = as.Date(c(
    "2005-05-31", "2005-08-05", "2005-09-12", "2005-10-05", "2005-11-12",
    "2005-11-26", "2005-11-30", "2006-01-31", "2006-03-31", "2006-04-11",
    "2006-04-30", "2006-05-28", "2006-05-31", "2006-06-10", "2006-06-15",
    "2006-08-31", "2006-09-09", "2006-09-13", "2006-09-18", "2006-10-07",
    "2006-10-31", "2006-10-31", "2006-11-08", "2006-11-30", "2006-12-11",
    "2007-01-05", "2007-01-13", "2007-01-24", "2007-01-29", "2007-01-31",
    "2007-03-24", "2007-04-13", "2007-04-14", "2007-04-23", "2007-04-30",
    "2007-04-30", "2007-05-06", "2007-05-09", "2007-05-13", "2007-05-23",
    "2007-05-27", "2007-05-31", "2007-06-03", "2007-06-05", "2007-06-13",
    "2007-06-22", "2007-06-30", "2007-06-30", "2007-07-13", "2007-07-22",
    "2007-07-31", "2007-08-13", "2007-08-14", "2007-08-21", "2007-08-31",
    "2007-08-31", "2007-08-31", "2007-09-05", "2007-09-13", "2007-09-14",
    "2007-09-20", "2007-09-30", "2007-09-30", "2007-09-30", "2007-10-05",
    "2007-10-13", "2007-10-20", "2007-10-27", "2007-10-31", "2007-10-31",
    "2007-10-31", "2007-11-05", "2007-11-12", "2007-11-13", "2007-11-19",
    "2007-11-30", "2007-11-30", "2007-11-30", "2007-12-05", "2007-12-13",
    "2007-12-19", "2007-12-24", "2007-12-31", "2007-12-31", "2007-12-31",
    "2008-01-04", "2008-01-05", "2008-01-05", "2008-01-09", "2008-01-09",
    "2008-01-10", "2008-01-11", "2008-01-12", "2008-01-13", "2008-01-17",
    "2008-01-18", "2008-01-18", "2008-01-21", "2008-01-27", "2008-01-31"
  )),
  amount = c(
    24.4, 7618, 21971, 5245, 2921, 8000, 169.2, 71.5, 14.6, 4214, 14.6, 13920,
    14.6, 24640, 1600, 261.1, 16400, 3500, 2700, 19882, 182, 14.6, 16927, 25653,
    3059, 2880, 9658, 4500, 12480, 14.6, 1000, 3679, 34430, 12600, 14.6, 19.2,
    4900, 826, 3679, 2100, 38000, 79, 11400, 21495, 3679, 200, 14.6, 100.6, 3679,
    5300, 108.9, 3679, 2696, 7500, 171.6, 14.6, 99.2, 2452, 3679, 3218, 700, 69.7,
    14.6, 91.5, 2452, 3679, 2900, 17572, 14.6, 14.6, 90.5, 2452, 49752, 3679,
    1900, 14.6, 870, 85.2, 2452, 3679, 1600, 540, 14.6, 14.6, 79, 210, 2452,
    28400, 720, 180, 420, 44289, 489, 3679, 840, 2900, 150, 870, 420, 14.6
  )
)
```

Comment: subsetting data is notoriously slow. Every loop (map is an optimized c loop) you are completely subsetting the data which takes a lot of time. It would be much faster to change your data so that you can do a group_by and mutate instead. The tsibble package or zoo package are good for doing time based operations.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example from your data... you can use `dput()`.

Comment: I did it @sindri_baldur

Comment: nice question, I changed the title to be more meaningful to your problem, feel free to edit to make it even better

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is simply a non-equi join in data.table. You can create a variable of `date - 180` and limit the join between the current date and that variable. This should be fairly quick

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, date_minus_180 := date - 180]
dt[, amnt_6_m := .SD[dt, sum(amount, na.rm = TRUE), 
     on = .(to = from, date <= date, date >= date_minus_180), by = .EACHI]$V1]
head(dt, 10)
#        id from   to       date  amount date_minus_180 amnt_6_m
#  1: 18529 5370 9356 2005-05-31    24.4     2004-12-02      0.0
#  2: 13742 5370 5605 2005-08-05  7618.0     2005-02-06      0.0
#  3:  9913 5370 8567 2005-09-12 21971.0     2005-03-16      0.0
#  4:   956 8605 5370 2005-10-05  5245.0     2005-04-08      0.0
#  5:  2557 5370 5636 2005-11-12  2921.0     2005-05-16   5245.0
#  6:  1602 6390 5370 2005-11-26  8000.0     2005-05-30      0.0
#  7: 18669 5370 8933 2005-11-30   169.2     2005-06-03  13245.0
#  8: 35900 5370 8483 2006-01-31    71.5     2005-08-04  13245.0
#  9: 48667 8934 5370 2006-03-31    14.6     2005-10-02      0.0
# 10: 51341 5370 7626 2006-04-11  4214.0     2005-10-13   8014.6
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setkey(df, to, date)

# Unique combination of from and date
af <- df[, unique(.SD), .SDcols = c("from", "date")]

# For each combination check sum of incoming in the last 6 months
for (i in 1:nrow(af)) {
  set(
    af, i = i, j = "am6m", 
    value = df[(date) %between% (af$date[[i]] - c(180, 0)) & to == af$from[[i]], sum(amount)]
  )
}
# Join the results into the main data.frame
df[, am6m := af[.SD, on = .(from, date), am6m]]



> tail(df)
#        id from   to       date  amount    am6m
# 1:  18529 5370 9356 2005-05-31    24.4     0.0
# 2: 258484 5370 9499 2008-01-09   720.0 74543.5
# 3: 251611 5370 9533 2007-12-31    14.6 46143.5
# 4:  83324 5370 9676 2006-08-31   261.1 40203.8
# 5: 203763 5370 9689 2007-08-31    14.6 92353.1
# 6: 103444 5370 9772 2006-11-08 16927.0 82671.2
```

Comment: It runs for 45 mins nearly and doesn't seem to be finished any time soon

Comment: I canceled the code, after an hour of runtime. So, it's a huge amount of time, considering I need to run 30 similar code blocks

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using window functions.

However, they require complete daily data in order to work, so the amount of memory required can be large (you have to have a row for every day for each from).

Also note that this method is only useful for large datasets or for performing calculations directly on a database. It takes a lot of set-up time to get the original data into a form that has no gaps. And it takes time to join the data at the end.

However, the slide function is relatively consistent in how fast it is regardless of size of data. As opposed to subsetting which increases in time as the size of the data being subset increases.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)

# Calculate the 6 month window
six_mo_rollup <- data %>% 
  ## NOTE: You have to deal with duplicates somehow...either remove
  ## false duplicates or make them not duplicates...
  # We can get a unique from/date combo by summing since we need
  # to sum anyway.
  group_by(from,date) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount),
            .groups = "keep") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Now that each from/date is unique
  # convert data to a tsibble object
  as_tsibble(key = c(from),index = date) %>%
  # window functions can't have any missing time periods...so fill gaps
  # window functions grab 180 rows...not 180 days from the date
  group_by_key() %>%
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # arrange data from lowest to highest so slide can work right.
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(from) %>%
  mutate(
    six_mo_sum = slide_dbl(
      amount,
      sum,
      na.rm = TRUE, 
      .size = 180, 
      .align = "right"
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # any row without amount was created by fill_gaps in the example
  # so we can drop those rows to save space
  filter(!is.na(amount))

six_mo_rollup %>% filter(from == "5370")
# # A tsibble: 41 x 4 [1D]
# # Key:       from [1]
# from  date        amount six_mo_sum
#  <chr>  <date>      <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 5370  2005-05-31    24.4        NA 
# 2 5370  2005-08-05  7618          NA 
# 3 5370  2005-09-12 21971          NA 
# 4 5370  2005-11-12  2921          NA 
# 5 5370  2005-11-30   169.      32679.
# 6 5370  2006-01-31    71.5     32751.
# 7 5370  2006-04-11  4214        7376.
# 8 5370  2006-08-31   261.       4475.
# 9 5370  2006-10-31   182         443.
# 10 5370  2006-11-08 16927       17370.
# # ... with 31 more rows

# Join the windowed data to the original dataset
data <- data %>%
  left_join(
    six_mo_rollup %>% select(from,date,six_mo_sum),
    by = c("from","date")
  )
```

---

UPDATE:

In the comments it became apparent that you wanted to sum up the to values for each for. I didn't understand that originally. The update to the code is to change all of the rollup to `to` instead of `for`.

Also, you wanted values that didn't have 6 months of complete data. So you add `.partial = TRUE`.

```
# Calculate the 6 month window
six_mo_rollup <- data %>% 
  ## NOTE: You have to deal with duplicates somehow...either remove
  ## false duplicates or make them not duplicates...
  # We can get a unique from/date combo by summing since we need
  # to sum anyway.
  group_by(to,date) %>%
  summarise(amount = sum(amount),
            .groups = "keep") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # Now that each from/date is unique
  # convert data to a tsibble object
  as_tsibble(key = c(to),index = date) %>%
  # window functions can't have any missing time periods...so fill gaps
  # window functions grab 180 rows...not 180 days from the date
  group_by_key() %>%
  fill_gaps(.full = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # arrange data from lowest to highest so slide can work right.
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(to) %>%
  mutate(
    six_mo_sum = slide_dbl(
      amount,
      sum,
      na.rm = TRUE, 
      .size = 180, 
      .align = "right",
      .partial = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # any row without amount was created by fill_gaps in the example
  # so we can drop those rows to save space
  filter(!is.na(amount))

six_mo_rollup %>% filter(to == "5370")
# # A tsibble: 50 x 4 [1D]
# # Key:       to [1]
# to    date        amount six_mo_sum
# <chr> <date>       <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 5370  2005-10-05  5245        5245 
# 2 5370  2005-11-26  8000       13245 
# 3 5370  2006-03-31    14.6     13260.
# 4 5370  2006-04-30    14.6      8029.
# 5 5370  2006-05-28 13920       13949.
# 6 5370  2006-05-31    14.6     13964.
# 7 5370  2006-06-10 24640       38604.
# 8 5370  2006-06-15  1600       40204.
# 9 5370  2006-09-09 16400       56604.
# 10 5370  2006-09-13  3500       60104.
# # ... with 40 more rows

# Join the windowed data to the original dataset
data <- data %>%
  left_join(
    six_mo_rollup %>% select(to,date,six_mo_sum),
    by = c("from" = "to","date" = "date")
  )
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the calculations? Since  the `six_mo_sum` should be ```0, 0, 0, 5245.0, 13245.0, 13245.0, 8014.6, 40203.8, 82671.2, 82671.2 ``` in the specified date order.

Comment: slide functions return NA by default if there are not 6 months of data available. For `from == "5370"` the first date is on 2005-05-31 so for this from value any date before 2005-11-27 will receive an NA value.

Comment: Also, I don't know how you intended to handle the `to` values or duplicate from/date combinations. So I rolled every from/date up and summed that up. If you wanted something different that would have to be accounted for.

Comment: Ah! You're summing up how much the from has received, not how much it has transferred.

Comment: Update added to post.

Answer (score 2):

A 1m record dataset is small enough that no parallelization is needed. There are many ways to do this that "look" right but are not... be careful!

First off, you may be wondering why is your original approach slow? R is an interpreted array language. To do anything with acceptable performance you have to pass vectors to fast functions that have been precompiled in lower level languages. If you "map" a function elementwise over a dataset you lose most of the advantages of vectorization - `purrr::map`, `base::lapply`, etc all fundamentally have comparable performance to a for loop with preallocation, ie. not great. You are making 1 million plus individual function calls (one per record). Parallelization of this can only improve performance by a factor of however many cores you have minus some overhead.

Clarifying questions for you:

- is there a limit of one transaction per day per account or are multiple transactions possible on any given day? I am assuming yes, multiple transactions per day are possible.
- "how much transaction amount the accounts in from column received in the last 6 month prior to the date that particular transaction was made" - I am assuming this means "ignore transactions made on the same date as the transaction getting the field appended to", as there is no way to determine what time these transactions were performed at

My approach: first sum by account and day, then calculate rolling sum by day, then join that to the subsequent day.

```
install.packages("RcppRoll") # for roll_sum()
install.packages(tidyr)      # for complete()

library(dplyr)

start_date <- as.Date("2018-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
window_size <- 180L

# your example dataset is way too small to assess performance.
# Here is a 100k record dataset.

big_data <- tibble(
  from = as.factor(sapply(1:1000L, function(x) sample(1:100L,100, replace = F))),
  to = as.factor(sapply(1:1000L, function(x) sample(1:100L,100, replace = F))),
  amount = sample(1:10000, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(seq.Date(from = start_date, to = end_date, by = "days"), 100000, replace = TRUE)
) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup()

# calculate daily sum of values from PRECEDING day for join
daily_summary <- big_data %>%
  group_by(to, date) %>%
  summarize(daily_sum = sum(amount, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # backfill empty records for data going back 6 months from start
  # this is needed because roll_sum() has no partial mode implemented.
  # and populate missing account - date combinations
  complete(date = seq.Date(from = start_date - window_size, to = end_date, by = "days"), to, fill = list(daily_sum = 0)) %>%
  group_by(to) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(
    total_trx_amount_received_in_last_sixmonth = RcppRoll::roll_sum(daily_sum, align = "right", n = window_size, fill = NA),
    date = date + 1
  ) %>%
  filter(date >= start_date) %>%
  select(date = date, from = to, total_trx_amount_received_in_last_sixmonth)

results <- left_join(big_data, daily_summary, by = c("from", "date"))
```

Now, what about performance? Much better than what you are reporting, at least for me. For a 100k record dataset (100 accounts, 2 years of information) I got 0.6 seconds on my laptop. For a 1m record dataset (1000 accounts, 2 years of information) I got 7-8 seconds using `microbenchmark`. Possible not the most efficient approach possible but quite acceptable considering that I did no optimization and did not employ `data.table` which is usually the key to high performance 2d operations in R.

Using `dplyr` grouping still means we are making one call to the fast precompiled function `RcppRoll::roll_sum()` per account, which is not ideal from a performance perspective, but at least we are only doing one function call per account rather than one function call per individual record. You might also want to look into the single pass rolling window functions implemented in the [RollingWindow](https://github.com/andrewuhl/RollingWindow) package as they may be even faster.