# How to use a custom function in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, igraph

This is my transaction data. It shows the transactions made from the accounts in `from` column to the accounts in `to` column with the date and the amount information

```
data 

id          from    to          date        amount  
<int>       <chr>   <chr>       <date>      <dbl>
19521       6644    6934        2005-01-01  700.0
19524       6753    8456        2005-01-01  600.0
19523       9242    9333        2005-01-01  1000.0
…           …       …           …           …
1056317     7819    7454        2010-12-31  60.2
1056318     6164    7497        2010-12-31  107.5
1056319     7533    7492        2010-12-31  164.1
```

I want to calculate `closeness centrality` measure on the networks of transactions made in the last 6 month prior to the date each particular transaction was made and want to save this information as a new column in the original data.

example data I'll use here is:

```
structure(list(id = c(83324L, 87614L, 88898L, 89874L, 94765L, 
100277L, 101587L), from = c("5370", "7816", "8046", "5492", "8756", 
"5370", "9254"), to = c("9676", "5370", "5370", "5370", "5370", 
"9105", "5370"), date = structure(c(13391, 13400, 13404, 13409, 
13428, 13452, 13452), class = "Date"), amount = c(261.1, 16400, 
3500, 2700, 19882, 182, 14.6)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, this following code works very well to accomplish this in a small dataset:

```
library(tnet)
closeness_fnc <- function(data){
  accounts <- data[date == max(date),from]
  id <- data[date == max(date),id]  
  
  # for directed networks
  df <- data %>% group_by(from, to) %>% mutate(weights = sum(amount)) %>% select(from, to, weights) %>% distinct
  cl <- closeness_w(df, directed = T, gconly=FALSE, alpha = 0.5) 
  
  list(
    id = id,
    closeness_directed = cl[,"n.closeness"][accounts]
  )

}

network_data <- data[, closeness_fnc(data[(date >= end_date - 180) & (date <= end_date)]), .(end_date = date)] %>% select(-end_date)
# adding this info into the original data
data <- merge(x = data, y = network_data, by = "id")
```

So, the output is as I expected:

```
# data
id      from    to      date        amount  closeness_directed 
<int>   <chr>   <chr>   <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> 
83324   5370    9676    2006-08-31  261.1   1.00000000
87614   7816    5370    2006-09-09  16400.0 0.98744695
88898   8046    5370    2006-09-13  3500.0  0.35329017
89874   5492    5370    2006-09-18  2700.0  0.25176754
94765   8756    5370    2006-10-07  19882.0 0.39233504
100277  5370    9105    2006-10-31  182.0   0.07167582
101587  9254    5370    2006-10-31  14.6    0.02390589
```

However, since my data has over 1 million rows, this code will take more than a day to complete(it runs for more than 12 hours and hasn't yet finished).

I had a similar running time problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63795371/sum-amount-last-6-month-prior-to-the-date-of-transaction) and I want to apply the same logic to this code. So, I modified my code as follows:

```
library(tnet)
closeness_fnc <- function(data){
  accounts <- data[date == max(date),from]
  id <- data[date == max(date),id]  
  
  # for directed networks
  df <- data %>% group_by(from, to) %>% mutate(weights = sum(amount)) %>% select(from, to, weights) %>% distinct
  cl <- closeness_w(df, directed = T, gconly=FALSE, alpha = 0.5) 
  
  closeness_directed <- cl[,"n.closeness"][accounts]
  closeness_directed <- as.data.frame(closeness_directed)
  closeness_directed$from <- rownames(closeness_directed)
  rownames(closeness_directed) <- NULL

  return(closeness_directed)
}

# this is the approach given in the link I provided:
setDT(data)[, date_minus_180 := date - 180]
data[, ':=' (closeness_directed = data[data, closeness_fnc(data), 
     on = .(from, date <= date, date >= date_minus_180), by = .EACHI]$closeness_directed
     )] %>% select(-date_minus_180)
```

however, that won't work obviously since

```
data[data, closeness_fnc(data), 
     on = .(from, date <= date, date >= date_minus_180), by = .EACHI]
```

gives the output

```
from   date         date     closeness_directed      from   
<chr>  <date>      <date>       <dbl>                <chr>

5370    2006-08-31  2006-03-04  0.07167582           5370
5370    2006-08-31  2006-03-04  0.02390589           9254
7816    2006-09-09  2006-03-13  0.07167582           5370
7816    2006-09-09  2006-03-13  0.02390589           9254
8046    2006-09-13  2006-03-17  0.07167582           5370
8046    2006-09-13  2006-03-17  0.02390589           9254
5492    2006-09-18  2006-03-22  0.07167582           5370
5492    2006-09-18  2006-03-22  0.02390589           9254
8756    2006-10-07  2006-04-10  0.07167582           5370
8756    2006-10-07  2006-04-10  0.02390589           9254
1-10 of 14 rows
```

So, now how can I adjust the code here to solve the problem?

> A larger dataset

```
structure(list(id = c(19521L, 19522L, 19523L, 19524L, 19525L, 
19526L, 19527L, 19528L, 19529L, 19530L, 19531L, 0L, 19532L, 19533L, 
19534L, 21971L, 21972L, 21973L, 21974L, 21975L, 21976L, 21977L, 
21978L, 21979L, 21980L, 21981L, 1L, 21761L, 21762L, 21763L, 21764L, 
21765L, 21766L, 21767L, 21982L, 21983L, 21984L, 21768L, 21769L, 
21770L, 21771L, 21772L, 21773L, 2L, 21774L, 21775L, 21776L, 21777L, 
21778L, 21779L, 21780L, 21781L, 21782L, 3L, 21783L, 21784L, 21785L, 
21786L, 21787L, 21788L, 21789L, 21790L, 21791L, 21792L, 21793L, 
21794L, 21795L, 21796L, 4L, 21797L, 21798L, 21799L, 21800L, 21801L, 
21802L, 21803L, 21804L, 21805L, 21806L, 21807L, 21808L, 21809L, 
21810L, 21811L, 21812L, 21813L, 21814L, 21815L, 5L, 21816L, 21817L, 
21818L, 21819L, 21820L, 21821L, 21822L, 21823L, 21824L, 21825L, 
21826L, 21827L, 21828L, 21829L, 21830L, 6L, 21831L, 21832L, 21833L, 
21834L, 21835L, 21836L, 21837L, 21838L, 7L, 21839L, 21840L, 21841L, 
21842L, 21843L, 21844L, 21845L, 21846L, 21847L, 21848L, 21849L, 
21850L, 21851L, 21852L, 21853L, 21854L, 21855L, 21856L, 21857L, 
8L, 21858L, 21859L, 9L, 10L, 21860L, 21861L, 21862L, 21863L, 
21864L, 21865L, 21866L, 21867L, 21868L, 21869L, 21870L, 21871L, 
21872L, 21873L, 21874L, 21875L, 21876L, 21877L, 21878L, 21879L, 
21880L, 21881L, 21882L, 21883L, 21884L, 21885L, 21886L, 21887L, 
21888L, 21889L, 21890L, 21891L, 21892L, 21893L, 21894L, 21895L, 
21896L, 21897L, 21898L, 21899L, 21900L, 11L, 21901L, 21902L, 
21903L, 21904L, 21905L, 21906L, 21907L, 21908L, 21909L, 12L, 
21910L, 21911L, 21912L, 21913L, 21914L, 21915L, 21916L, 21917L, 
21918L, 21919L, 13L, 21920L, 21921L, 21922L, 21923L, 21924L, 
21925L, 21926L, 21927L, 21928L, 21929L, 21930L, 21931L, 21932L, 
21933L, 21934L, 21935L, 21936L, 14L, 21937L, 21938L, 21939L, 
21940L, 21941L, 21942L, 21957L, 21958L, 21959L, 21960L, 21961L, 
21962L, 21963L, 21964L, 15L, 21965L, 21966L, 21967L, 21968L, 
21969L, 21970L, 21985L, 21986L, 21987L, 21988L, 21989L, 21990L, 
21991L, 21992L, 21993L, 21994L, 21995L, 21996L, 16L, 17L, 21551L, 
21552L, 21553L, 21554L, 21555L, 21556L, 21557L, 21558L, 21559L, 
21560L, 21561L, 21562L, 21563L, 21564L, 21565L, 21566L, 21567L, 
21997L, 21998L, 18L, 21568L, 21569L, 21570L, 21571L, 21572L, 
21573L, 21574L, 21575L, 21576L, 21577L, 21578L, 21579L, 21580L, 
21581L, 19L, 21582L, 21583L, 21584L, 21585L, 21586L, 21587L, 
21588L, 21589L, 21590L, 21591L, 21592L, 20L, 21593L, 21594L, 
21595L, 21596L, 21597L, 21598L, 21599L, 21600L, 21601L, 21602L, 
21603L, 21604L, 21605L, 21606L, 21L, 21607L, 21608L, 21609L, 
21610L, 21611L, 21612L, 21613L, 21614L, 21615L, 21616L, 21617L, 
21618L, 21619L, 21620L, 21621L, 21622L, 21623L, 21624L, 21625L, 
21626L, 22L, 21627L, 21628L, 21629L, 21630L, 21631L, 21632L, 
21633L, 21634L, 21635L, 21636L, 21637L, 21638L, 21639L, 21640L, 
21641L, 21642L, 21643L, 21644L, 21645L, 23L, 21646L, 21647L, 
21648L, 21649L, 21650L, 21651L, 21652L, 21653L, 21654L, 21655L, 
21656L, 21657L, 21658L, 24L, 21659L, 21660L, 21661L, 21662L, 
21663L, 21664L, 21665L, 21666L, 21667L, 21668L, 21669L, 25L, 
21670L, 21671L, 21672L, 21673L, 21674L, 21675L, 21676L, 21677L, 
21678L, 21679L, 21680L, 21681L, 21682L, 21683L, 26L, 21684L, 
21685L, 21686L, 21687L, 21688L, 21689L, 21690L, 21691L, 21692L, 
21693L, 21694L, 21695L, 21696L, 21697L, 21698L, 21699L, 21700L, 
21701L, 21702L, 21703L, 27L, 21704L, 21719L, 21720L, 21721L, 
21722L, 21723L, 21724L, 21725L, 21726L, 21727L, 21728L, 21729L, 
21730L, 21731L, 21732L, 28L, 21733L, 21734L, 21735L, 21736L, 
21737L, 21738L, 21739L, 21740L, 29L, 21741L, 21742L, 21743L, 
21744L, 21745L, 21746L, 21747L, 21748L, 21749L, 21750L, 21751L, 
21752L, 21753L, 21754L, 21755L, 21756L, 21757L, 21758L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 21229L, 21230L, 21231L, 21232L, 
21233L, 21234L, 21235L, 21236L, 21237L, 21238L, 21239L, 21240L, 
21241L, 21242L, 21243L, 21244L, 21245L, 21246L, 21247L, 21248L, 
21249L, 21250L, 21251L, 21252L, 21253L, 21254L, 21255L, 21256L, 
21257L, 21258L), from = c("6644", "9843", "9242", "6753", "7075", 
"8685", "5513", "6340", "6042", "5587", "7237", "5695", "9582", 
"8539", "7939", "9077", "8946", "5591", "8380", "5865", "7867", 
"9457", "6968", "7971", "6150", "9361", "9379", "8409", "9740", 
"7226", "7531", "6752", "7362", "6661", "5730", "5417", "9049", 
"7057", "6252", "9476", "6228", "8896", "7371", "8170", "7122", 
"6694", "5450", "9435", "5619", "8289", "9862", "5504", "6555", 
"9845", "7537", "9482", "6810", "8257", "8490", "6588", "9652", 
"7303", "5852", "5746", "9198", "6917", "8688", "9460", "9640", 
"7054", "8628", "7065", "9006", "6832", "6185", "8422", "6914", 
"7069", "7848", "8436", "5494", "6375", "5653", "8912", "9794", 
"8413", "6527", "9101", "5815", "6923", "8184", "6811", "8130", 
"6539", "8643", "6329", "7744", "8211", "9641", "8003", "5599", 
"8715", "7108", "9573", "8583", "5648", "6444", "5660", "8191", 
"9830", "5931", "7921", "6753", "8314", "7940", "6265", "6604", 
"6509", "5618", "5860", "6469", "9525", "5887", "6626", "7145", 
"6862", "5741", "9144", "9862", "9163", "7297", "7599", "8427", 
"8865", "9418", "8636", "6530", "9155", "6934", "8817", "9028", 
"5521", "5943", "7443", "9557", "8239", "6819", "9761", "5983", 
"6830", "6368", "5381", "8782", "8008", "9160", "9862", "8008", 
"9615", "6920", "6164", "6278", "9729", "8960", "6358", "5939", 
"8902", "9522", "7344", "9070", "6594", "8058", "6639", "7896", 
"6325", "7804", "9554", "9725", "8475", "7746", "7536", "9671", 
"9761", "5415", "6837", "8327", "9061", "8981", "9226", "5862", 
"7085", "8925", "6226", "6849", "8432", "9545", "5837", "5440", 
"9732", "8695", "7690", "5829", "9373", "7977", "6361", "7320", 
"7603", "6303", "7077", "7850", "5792", "9588", "9204", "8648", 
"8950", "7106", "6334", "6843", "7060", "9606", "5520", "9725", 
"9350", "7463", "8130", "7947", "9668", "9490", "6241", "8830", 
"6374", "9528", "7919", "8532", "6795", "6934", "8162", "9275", 
"8106", "8615", "9206", "8283", "6265", "7052", "7737", "8422", 
"7815", "9028", "7932", "6125", "6671", "7800", "9835", "5573", 
"7874", "8931", "6748", "8192", "6822", "6950", "8020", "8555", 
"8986", "7644", "5736", "8421", "6224", "8374", "8304", "9101", 
"8677", "9208", "7008", "6074", "9409", "6269", "9721", "9304", 
"9117", "5420", "9691", "7728", "8422", "8579", "7495", "9838", 
"8139", "9571", "5385", "5454", "9620", "7723", "9249", "7033", 
"7966", "5837", "9844", "5793", "5747", "6362", "6925", "9318", 
"6780", "6934", "7150", "6818", "7246", "5514", "9574", "7838", 
"5540", "6646", "6893", "6417", "8039", "8721", "8763", "6401", 
"6510", "7970", "7117", "6001", "7505", "7646", "5600", "6522", 
"8395", "5601", "5418", "6296", "8790", "7622", "9012", "8165", 
"7624", "5468", "9316", "9030", "7155", "5702", "7492", "8503", 
"9868", "6807", "6404", "9076", "7213", "8735", "7849", "8551", 
"9351", "6693", "6795", "9653", "9504", "6948", "9358", "9280", 
"8168", "5456", "9138", "8420", "9312", "8930", "6375", "8695", 
"7699", "6748", "5506", "9475", "5776", "5517", "5644", "8680", 
"5474", "7534", "9363", "9586", "6508", "6193", "5401", "8032", 
"8461", "9387", "5812", "7564", "5917", "5434", "5794", "7840", 
"9085", "8331", "7060", "7175", "6669", "8896", "6352", "7432", 
"9810", "8776", "6934", "6112", "8869", "8248", "9450", "6974", 
"7264", "7336", "6880", "7866", "7777", "7502", "5615", "9777", 
"7371", "9214", "6374", "6039", "7714", "9056", "8358", "8963", 
"8657", "8846", "9319", "7220", "7764", "8967", "8683", "9137", 
"6971", "9747", "7449", "8259", "5373", "7300", "6273", "8391", 
"7862", "5696", "6622", "5456", "9240", "7021", "7313", "7247", 
"6679", "8102", "6812", "9473", "6345", "7935", "9696", "5541", 
"8939", "5417", "6887", "8998", "7977", "9110", "8666", "6670", 
"8975", "7518", "5601", "7549", "7841", "8888", "5808", "9545", 
"9460", "9361", "9807", "6860", "9811", "5935", "8966", "8684", 
"5915", "8892", "8493", "7894", "6342", "6382", "8461", "7833", 
"7201", "7253", "6720", "6175", "9201", "5682", "5473", "7173", 
"6094", "8810", "5874", "6947", "8462", "6885", "6201"), to = c("6934", 
"9115", "9333", "8456", "6510", "7207", "6046", "7047", "6213", 
"9493", "6248", "7468", "8925", "6727", "6912", "6727", "9811", 
"9493", "9251", "6375", "6460", "6375", "8130", "5773", "6510", 
"6951", "6213", "6671", "6153", "6634", "9440", "8220", "8512", 
"8105", "8786", "5773", "6454", "5997", "8374", "7207", "6253", 
"9251", "8456", "7517", "6935", "6143", "8220", "9628", "5837", 
"9115", "6517", "9628", "8078", "6143", "6912", "7047", "6460", 
"7517", "6442", "9333", "6646", "5997", "8395", "6153", "9012", 
"6248", "7468", "8105", "6254", "9811", "7518", "6217", "6951", 
"8551", "9012", "5605", "6671", "7084", "8925", "5985", "8130", 
"5443", "8665", "8657", "8395", "6883", "6334", "8472", "6669", 
"5715", "5409", "8876", "8869", "9450", "5610", "6934", "6043", 
"7253", "6646", "7564", "6934", "5668", "6986", "7382", "6934", 
"8671", "6646", "8336", "9750", "8967", "9137", "8912", "5373", 
"9240", "6934", "8925", "6273", "6566", "6164", "9240", "6145", 
"7247", "7134", "5606", "9682", "5635", "8820", "8763", "7492", 
"5837", "6634", "8323", "6616", "6374", "8678", "7293", "6143", 
"8105", "7843", "6375", "7207", "5997", "9628", "9240", "9811", 
"5837", "8395", "8456", "9811", "9333", "9251", "6153", "6213", 
"6248", "9115", "8925", "6634", "6671", "8130", "6646", "9333", 
"6727", "6510", "6460", "8220", "9493", "9750", "6934", "6912", 
"6951", "7047", "9012", "9750", "5773", "7517", "7468", "8456", 
"7207", "6192", "9131", "6046", "7143", "7047", "6213", "6333", 
"7603", "6248", "9620", "6995", "9770", "5835", "8925", "5614", 
"8846", "8134", "7468", "8887", "8631", "9744", "9251", "6217", 
"6934", "7247", "8697", "6727", "5606", "9664", "6460", "6442", 
"8374", "6334", "9440", "9493", "9845", "7492", "5605", "8078", 
"9202", "6454", "5635", "8657", "8606", "8395", "9037", "5773", 
"6951", "6807", "9770", "8631", "9845", "8512", "6253", "6989", 
"6375", "7248", "8665", "8786", "8887", "5668", "6374", "6883", 
"9519", "8134", "6510", "5443", "6646", "6634", "5373", "7084", 
"6033", "8967", "8105", "9565", "9723", "8925", "7222", "6361", 
"8739", "8739", "6502", "9085", "5980", "5980", "5385", "5773", 
"7001", "9200", "7603", "7471", "9620", "5610", "6794", "9457", 
"8336", "6935", "5409", "5621", "5614", "9664", "7517", "7518", 
"6669", "6517", "6114", "7207", "9628", "9251", "8456", "8078", 
"6935", "6772", "9535", "8869", "7222", "7034", "6986", "6566", 
"8220", "7155", "7446", "9202", "6934", "9333", "6046", "9535", 
"8678", "6273", "6896", "7345", "9115", "8183", "6634", "6254", 
"7471", "9628", "9333", "9457", "9457", "9137", "6043", "8671", 
"6479", "6503", "5715", "7143", "5592", "6912", "7047", "6460", 
"7517", "6143", "9712", "8472", "7382", "6995", "6192", "7518", 
"6145", "8912", "6844", "7253", "7109", "8763", "5997", "5985", 
"6807", "6153", "6329", "7213", "8551", "7564", "7155", "6248", 
"7468", "8105", "5605", "6503", "8820", "5562", "8697", "7109", 
"9811", "6984", "6951", "8323", "9450", "9012", "6616", "5922", 
"9682", "9839", "8041", "5443", "9039", "8178", "7293", "8665", 
"8657", "8846", "7990", "8168", "7646", "8472", "9803", "8041", 
"8879", "9085", "8178", "7624", "8221", "5776", "8422", "9085", 
"8545", "8321", "5473", "6994", "6673", "6934", "7769", "5409", 
"6104", "8876", "7818", "8941", "5610", "7825", "7770", "6043", 
"7253", "8790", "7564", "8178", "8846", "6954", "7382", "6986", 
"6194", "8671", "9741", "5384", "8846", "8653", "6659", "9750", 
"9744", "9138", "9321", "7124", "8912", "5866", "7718", "5468", 
"7321", "6795", "6042", "6566", "6164", "9084", "6507", "9033", 
"6807", "9240", "6540", "6857", "8945", "7134", "5606", "9390", 
"9682", "6359", "8757", "8763", "8280", "7049", "6205", "7604", 
"9729", "7492", "6085", "8239", "6299", "9845", "9240", "8323", 
"6616", "6671", "6669", "8657", "7471", "9744", "5443", "5837", 
"8395", "8551", "8456", "8472", "8374", "5610", "9811", "9682", 
"9333", "9251", "9202", "7603", "6192", "6143", "6153", "6329", 
"6213", "6273", "6248", "7109", "7143", "8041", "8665", "8925", 
"9115", "6634", "6671"), date = structure(c(12784, 12784, 12784, 
12784, 12785, 12785, 12786, 12786, 12786, 12786, 12786, 12787, 
12787, 12787, 12787, 12788, 12788, 12788, 12788, 12789, 12789, 
12790, 12790, 12790, 12790, 12790, 12791, 12791, 12791, 12791, 
12791, 12791, 12791, 12791, 12791, 12791, 12791, 12792, 12792, 
12792, 12792, 12792, 12792, 12793, 12793, 12793, 12793, 12793, 
12794, 12794, 12794, 12794, 12794, 12795, 12795, 12795, 12795, 
12795, 12795, 12795, 12795, 12796, 12796, 12796, 12796, 12796, 
12796, 12796, 12797, 12797, 12797, 12797, 12797, 12797, 12797, 
12797, 12798, 12798, 12799, 12800, 12800, 12800, 12801, 12801, 
12801, 12802, 12802, 12802, 12803, 12803, 12804, 12804, 12804, 
12804, 12804, 12805, 12805, 12805, 12805, 12805, 12806, 12806, 
12806, 12806, 12807, 12807, 12807, 12807, 12807, 12807, 12808, 
12808, 12808, 12809, 12809, 12809, 12809, 12809, 12809, 12809, 
12810, 12810, 12810, 12810, 12810, 12811, 12811, 12811, 12811, 
12812, 12812, 12812, 12812, 12813, 12813, 12813, 12814, 12814, 
12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 
12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 
12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 
12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 12814, 
12814, 12814, 12814, 12815, 12815, 12816, 12816, 12816, 12816, 
12816, 12816, 12816, 12816, 12816, 12816, 12817, 12817, 12817, 
12817, 12817, 12817, 12817, 12818, 12818, 12818, 12818, 12819, 
12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 
12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12819, 12820, 
12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 
12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12820, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 
12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 
12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12821, 12822, 12822, 12822, 
12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 
12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 12822, 
12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 
12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12823, 12824, 12824, 12824, 
12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 12824, 
12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 
12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12825, 12826, 12826, 12826, 
12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 
12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 12826, 
12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 
12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 12827, 
12827, 12827, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 
12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12828, 12829, 12829, 12830, 12830, 
12830, 12830, 12830, 12830, 12831, 12831, 12831, 12831, 12831, 
12831, 12832, 12832, 12832, 12832, 12832, 12832, 12832, 12832, 
12833, 12833, 12833, 12833, 12833, 12833, 12833, 12834, 12834, 
12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 12834, 
12835, 12835, 12835, 12835, 12835, 12836, 12836, 12836, 12836, 
12836, 12837, 12837, 12837, 12837, 12837, 12837, 12837, 12837, 
12837, 12837, 12838, 12838, 12838, 12838, 12838, 12838, 12839, 
12839, 12839, 12839, 12839, 12839, 12839, 12839, 12839, 12840, 
12840, 12840, 12840, 12840, 12840, 12840, 12841, 12841, 12841, 
12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 12841, 
12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 
12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 
12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 
12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 12842, 
12842, 12842), class = "Date"), amount = c(700, 900, 1000, 600, 
400, 1100, 600, 1100, 200, 800, 1000, 700, 300, 800, 800, 5123, 
400, 3401, 700, 500, 700, 3242, 500, 400, 5298, 900, 11832, 300, 
500, 600, 1100, 600, 300, 800, 400, 6774, 300, 200, 400, 14264, 
900, 13851, 17366, 1000, 800, 700, 6007, 500, 400, 6207, 900, 
12644, 800, 4276, 6434, 14779, 4507, 6446, 800, 17477, 1100, 
5009, 1000, 5718, 800, 13967, 6959, 15914, 200, 4470, 600, 800, 
10737, 700, 44749, 1000, 46552, 500, 13156, 1000, 23323, 1100, 
200, 300, 10792, 200, 400, 700, 200, 700, 1100, 1000, 700, 500, 
1100, 7268, 300, 200, 16125, 400, 14440, 700, 900, 300, 49752, 
200, 36518, 500, 900, 300, 900, 1000, 200, 19961, 21899, 12336, 
1100, 200, 700, 1100, 900, 1100, 800, 600, 400, 200, 500, 200, 
200, 38000, 16983, 1000, 300, 1000, 300, 800, 13.4, 42.7, 34700, 
12.6, 47.5, 13.3, 37.1, 17, 11.1, 15.5, 22.2, 55.8, 11.8, 50.1, 
45, 15.9, 38.8, 38.2, 20.1, 38.9, 7.1, 107.1, 48, 62.4, 2900, 
21.5, 19.1, 14, 19.5, 15.2, 5282, 94.7, 19.4, 28.2, 42.7, 110.2, 
0.8, 23.1, 20, 19.6, 2000, 5100, 1100, 200, 11900, 1100, 5500, 
7500, 1100, 800, 6000, 200, 600, 800, 25300, 45647, 1000, 700, 
600, 7000, 700, 900, 300, 2900, 5224, 30192, 24381, 400, 5123, 
23330, 700, 8500, 3191, 23041, 5029, 6238, 3401, 900, 20213, 
7618, 19935, 600, 5859, 3375, 12817, 500, 38645, 1600, 10600, 
5500, 700, 3217, 14626, 4550, 4356, 6689, 600, 3242, 9612, 5080, 
5039, 12785, 4212, 17632, 3395, 200, 3399, 5298, 14493, 28157, 
1800, 31348, 5544, 14100, 33045, 1800, 200, 800, 20066, 400, 
1000, 27666, 500, 600, 700, 700, 3151, 1000, 6774, 800, 1500, 
22452, 1100, 44333, 18347, 200, 600, 6242, 13900, 19746, 400, 
48098, 7041, 9100, 10584, 49590, 3021, 500, 14264, 5400, 13851, 
17366, 1200, 5072, 1100, 1100, 47831, 12015, 5200, 8905, 23524, 
6007, 1000, 300, 22349, 31038, 25200, 43737, 12154, 23736, 24863, 
400, 200, 6207, 29700, 14622, 4758, 5810, 12644, 17477, 19588, 
27078, 32594, 25609, 20281, 700, 900, 6310, 14319, 14400, 6434, 
14779, 4507, 6446, 4276, 9600, 13875, 12043, 4391, 4327, 9000, 
6698, 16392, 700, 15263, 1100, 18729, 5009, 3098, 4729, 5718, 
700, 500, 24400, 9658, 14963, 13967, 6959, 15914, 9800, 20567, 
3058, 600, 18497, 6148, 4470, 400, 10737, 15447, 24009, 44749, 
12138, 900, 800, 1000, 900, 4200, 700, 1100, 1300, 8000, 6000, 
29511, 200, 900, 600, 6600, 1100, 44162, 600, 24023, 900, 400, 
200, 300, 800, 33410, 14800, 400, 800, 500, 500, 19136, 33900, 
4100, 10500, 13400, 600, 700, 3700, 1000, 1000, 100, 3300, 800, 
9400, 45925, 41740, 500, 6200, 8000, 200, 3100, 500, 300, 31332, 
62100, 600, 7100, 28361, 4000, 200, 4500, 900, 900, 900, 1000, 
1500, 300, 2500, 2700, 11000, 300, 800, 900, 8900, 23990, 1100, 
1400, 800, 10700, 1800, 1100, 10900, 900, 200, 5200, 800, 200, 
800, 200, 900, 3900, 900, 600, 900, 18.7, 102, 2.9, 3, 39285, 
52.1, 34.1, 18.5, 21.3, 38.3, 160, 110.5, 58.6, 83.4, 34.7, 68.6, 
31, 20.3, 5.4, 89.3, 110.6, 61.5, 72.7, 13.7, 20.7, 25.9, 2.9, 
50.1, 14, 110, 16.2, 39, 73.8, 23.7, 249, 29.6, 117.3, 199)), row.names = c(NA, 
-500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think your bottle neck is `tnet::closeness_w`. It looks very slow and if you need to do it per join, it will be slow. I'm also not sure how it works with your data as `to` and `from` supposed to be numeric rather character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider re-writing your `closeness_func` as follows:

```
closeness_info <- function(from, DT) {
  DT <- DT[, .(weights = sum(amount)), by = .(from, to)]
  res <- closeness_w(DT, TRUE, FALSE, alpha = 0.5)
  `names<-`(res[, "n.closeness"], row.names(res))[from]
}
```

Then you can use the following `data.table` operation to achieve your goal:

```
set_closeness <- function(DT) {
  DT[, closeness_directed := closeness_info(.SD$from, DT[between(date, .BY$date - 180, .BY$date), ]), by = date]
}
```

Now let's benchmark the performances of this implementation against your original one with the long dataset you provide. Here I call it `df`. We first create two copies of that dataset. This is necessary as `data.table` by default uses pass-by-reference. If we do not create two copies of the dataset, then the following tests will always be applied to the same object (i.e. `df`).

```
data1 <- copy(df)
data2 <- copy(df)
```

We apply your original implementation to `data1`:

```
> system.time({
+   closeness_fnc <- function(data){
+     accounts <- data[date == max(date),from]
+     id <- data[date == max(date),id]  
+     
+     # for directed networks
+     df <- data %>% group_by(from, to) %>% mutate(weights = sum(amount)) %>% select(from, to, weights) %>% distinct
+     cl <- closeness_w(df, directed = T, gconly=FALSE, alpha = 0.5) 
+     
+     list(
+       id = id,
+       closeness_directed = cl[,"n.closeness"][accounts]
+     )
+     
+   }
+   network_data <- data1[, closeness_fnc(data1[(date >= end_date - 180) & (date <= end_date)]), .(end_date = date)] %>% select(-end_date)
+   data1 <- merge(x = data1, y = network_data, by = "id")
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   1.19    0.07    1.26
```

Then we apply the new implementation above to `data2`:

```
> system.time({
+   closeness_info <- function(from, DT) {
+     DT <- DT[, .(weights = sum(amount)), by = .(from, to)]
+     res <- closeness_w(DT, TRUE, FALSE, alpha = 0.5)
+     `names<-`(res[, "n.closeness"], row.names(res))[from]
+   }
+   set_closeness <- function(DT) {
+     DT[, closeness_directed := closeness_info(.SD$from, DT[between(date, .BY$date - 180, .BY$date), ]), by = date]
+   }
+   set_closeness(data2)
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.33    0.07    0.40
```

Do they produce the same set of results?

```
> all(data1[order(id), ] == data2[order(id), ])
[1] TRUE
```

Output:

```
> data2[order(id), ]
        id from   to       date amount closeness_directed
  1:     0 5695 7468 2005-01-04    700       0.0344016544
  2:     1 9379 6213 2005-01-08  11832       0.0492013976
  3:     2 8170 7517 2005-01-10   1000       0.0097043019
  4:     3 9845 6143 2005-01-12   4276       0.0142486370
  5:     4 9640 6254 2005-01-14    200       0.0022874217
 ---                                                     
496: 21994 6671 6033 2005-02-07  14100       0.0064464840
497: 21995 7800 8967 2005-02-07  33045       0.0098688428
498: 21996 9835 8105 2005-02-07   1800       0.0023032952
499: 21997 7008 6794 2005-02-08    200       0.0006955321
500: 21998 6074 9457 2005-02-08    600       0.0026025058
```

I think this might be the best performance you can get given that you do not want to rewrite the `closeness_w` function, which is probably the bottleneck here as per David's advice.

Comment: Thanks! This one took 8 hours to complete. Better solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it:

```r
closeness_fnc <- function(DT, grp){
  cl <- tnet::closeness_w(DT[, 
                             sum(amount),
                             by = .(from, to)], 
                          directed = T,
                          gconly=FALSE, 
                          alpha = 0.5) 
  
  ind = DT[date == max(date), from]
  cl[ind,"n.closeness"]))
}

setDT(data)
data[, closeness_directed := closeness_fnc(data[(date >= end_date - 180) & (date <= end_date)]), by = .(end_date = date)]

##     end_date     id closeness_directed
##       <Date>  <int>              <num>
##1: 2006-08-31  83324         1.00000000
##2: 2006-09-09  87614         0.98744695
##3: 2006-09-13  88898         0.35329017
##4: 2006-09-18  89874         0.25176754
##5: 2006-10-07  94765         0.39233504
##6: 2006-10-31 100277         0.07167582
##7: 2006-10-31 101587         0.02390589
```

Note, the `closeness_fnc()` was just simplified to use only [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table). The [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) code could have similar adjustments. Then I mainly used your original approach which seemed to work well.

*Edit*
Part of the problem is that we're aggregating each from and to for every date. We can instead do the aggregation all at once and create a lookup table.

```r
closeness_fx3 = function(from, to, amount, date) {
  cl = closeness_w(data.frame(from, to, amount),
                   directed = TRUE,
                   gconly = FALSE,
                   alpha = 0.5)
  
  cl[from[date == max(date)], "n.closeness"]
}

setDT(data)
agg_data = data[, .(tot_amount = sum(amount)), by = .(date)]
agg_data[, end_date := date - 180]

data[, 
      closeness_directed := .SD[agg_data,
                                on = .(date >= end_date,
                                       date <= date),
                                closeness_fx3(from, to, amount, x.date),
                                by = .EACHI]$V1
]
data
```

Using `bench::mark` which includes checking results for equality, this method is slightly faster than other solutions.

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr>      <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 simple_refactor 414ms  592ms      1.81     188MB     2.89    10    16      5.54s
2 ekoam           337ms  356ms      2.39     183MB     3.59    10    15      4.18s
3 use_agg         299ms  314ms      2.77     178MB     3.88    10    14       3.6s
```

Comment: Thank you, but `data[, closeness_fnc(data[(date >= end_date - 180) & (date <= end_date)]), by = .(end_date = date)]` is the part that slows the overall performance.  That's why I wanted to use `data[, ':=' (closeness_directed = data[data, closeness_fnc(data), 
     on = .(from, date <= date, date >= date_minus_180), by = .EACHI]$closeness_directed
     )] %>% select(-date_minus_180)` approach.

Comment: I see. The alternative approach does not work, though. You need more of a cartesian product. I will think about this and if I do not come up with something, I'll delete. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a better dataset? One that may be more representative? This one is difficult because it is so small that I cannot really test speedups.

Comment: I could only add a dataset with 500 rows because of the limitation. Hopefully, that's also enough @Cole However, it will run fast on such data

Comment: Ok, see edit. Note, my original method was pretty performant. although I did edit original to include ```:=```.

Comment: I don't know why but it gives this error: "Error in as.tnet(net, type = "weighted one-mode tnet") : There are duplicated entries in the edgelist"

Comment: On example data or real data?

Comment: On the real data.